# How can I make testng object run list of classes in java and make reportNG webpage?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, testng, reportng

I want to make custom report using testng + reportNG(both installed)

I m writing java file to run selected classes, 
i m using testNG api, but can't figure out how to call its methods and make my own suite

**I already have xml file that runs all eight java tests - suite_basic_links_working.xml**
I want to learn how to write java, not xml file to run same suite!

```
    public class Suite_runner_tets_links {
    TestNG suite_for_testing_links ;
    @Test
    public void main() {
      suite_for_testing_links.setDefaultSuiteName("NAIMI.KZ selenium + testng report ");
      List <> some_classes_to_run[] = new ArrayList();

      some_classes_to_run.add("C:\\Users\\www\\ERJAN_NAIMIKZ_ALL\\erjan_2_naimikz_test\\erjan\\testNG\\links_test\\Onas_url_click_test.java");
      some_classes_to_run.add("C:\\Users\\www\\ERJAN_NAIMIKZ_ALL\\erjan_2_naimikz_test\\erjan\\testNG\\links_test\\Podbo_specialista_url_click_test.java");

      suite_for_testing_links.setTestClasses(some_classes_to_run);
      suite_for_testing_links.run();
    /*  
      TestNG tng = new TestNG();
      List suites = Lists.newArrayList();
      suites.add("c:/tests/testng1.xml");
      suites.add("c:/tests/testng2.xml");
      tng.setTestSuites(suites);
      tng.run();*/

  }
  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() {
      suite_for_testing_links = new TestNG();
      System.out.println("here!!! "+suite_for_testing_links.getOutputDirectory()) ;
      suite_for_testing_links.setOutputDirectory("C:\\Users\\www\\ERJAN_NAIMIKZ_ALL\\erjan_2_naimikz_test\\erjan_custom_testng_report");
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {

  }
```

this is my directory in eclipse, i want to run 2 tests - blog_url_click_test.java and logo_url_clik test.

[image: k]

Answer (score 0):

Look at TestNG project website.  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html
You can easily find a @Factory example where you can put all of your test class into one method and then just run it.

```
public class WebTestFactory {

      @Factory
      public Object[] createInstances() {
       Object[] result = new Object[10]; 
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          result[i] = new WebTest(i * 10);
        }
        return result;
      }
    }
```

When you start this code you should notice that objects initializing is random. And if you want to make some hierarchy you will need to read for example this topic [How to order TestNG Factory execution given a single method test and sortable test data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172360/how-to-order-testng-factory-execution-given-a-single-method-test-and-sortable-te)